# React-Native run android error java is not incremential and react-native upgrade dismatch version with node_module

Tags: android, react-native, node-modules

I just started my project with the init command `create-react-native-app` and I installed all prerequires.

I have some problems with the command `react-native run-android` I got this error

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
```

I tried to search about it and people are talking about upgrading react-native but when I try to "react-native-git-upgrade" i got an error with version of my "package.json".

```
    git-upgrade info Check for updates 
git-upgrade info Read package.json files 
git-upgrade info Check declared version 
git-upgrade info Check matching versions 
git-upgrade ERR! An error occurred during upgrade: 
git-upgrade ERR! Error: react-native version in "package.json" (https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz) doesn't match the installed version in "node_modules" (0.55.4).
Try running "npm install" to fix this.
    at checkMatchingVersions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-git-upgrade/checks.js:24:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-git-upgrade/cliEntry.js:253:5)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-git-upgrade/cliEntry.js:171:191)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-git-upgrade/cliEntry.js:171:361
    at tryCallOne (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-git-upgrade/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-git-upgrade/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-git-upgrade/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

When I do `npm install` nothing change, I tried to delete my node_modules directory and create new one with `npm install` but it doesn't change.

I'm on Ubuntu and I'm struggling with this since few days ...

Answer (score 0):

I think these steps will help you.

1. Go to your project directory and run this command [Ubuntu: `cd
   android && ./gradlew clean`]
2. Delete build folder from android directory, assuming you are in android directory [`rm -rf build` in Ubuntu]
3. If this steps doesn’t produce any result then follow steps [1,2]
   and then remove **node_modules** directory and run `npm install` after
   following [1,2] from the **root directory of your project** .
4. Finally, go with this command `react-native run-android` from **project root**.